# Game development with Unity option is Unavailable

Tags: unity, visual-studio

When I am trying to download"Game development with Unity" from the visual studio 2017  the option says it's"Unavailable".. How to download this? 
So  question is :
Ques. : How to select the option which says "Unavailable" in the "visual studio installer"?

Comment: Via the [Unity web site](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download) or Unity hub?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but I don't know how to help you in downloading Unity from Visual Studio 2017. But I have another idea:

Why download Unity from Visual Studio 2017? You don't need it, you can download it from the Unity page, it's very simple. Even more, if you download it from Visual Studio you might download an older version of Unity (I have understood that Visual Studio takes some time to update it).

If you only want to download a single version of Unity you can do it from [this link](https://store.unity.com/download?ref=personal). If you instead plant to have several Unity versions (for compatibility with older projects) you can download the Unity HUB (a program which "manages" your Unity versions) from the same link, in the `Unity HUB` button.

In order to use Visual Studio 2017 to edit your Unity Script simply go to `Unity preferences` > `External tools` > `External script editor` and choose `Visual Studio`. Easy, right? The same instructions can be found [in Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VisualStudioIntegration.html).

I know this answer isn't exactly an answer to your question, but I hope it helps. If you aren't agree with this post, I will delete it.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. To be more specific, I want to write a script associated with player and when I am trying to open it in visual studio 2017 it is giving me error,"Project Target Framework Not Installed" and after some time the player script opens but in that auto completion is not happening. Some resources said that it is because windows is not updated to latest version and currently it is on updation.

Comment: @shubhamsharma oh, that is weird. 1) Which is your Windows version? 10? Check for its updates in Windows Update. 2) Do you have the last version of VS? You can check that in Visual Studio Installer, if not, update. 3) Check your Unity version, 2018?. Sometimes a simples updates fixes everything. 4) In Unity. Have you go to preferences and set VS as external script editor. 5) Did you double-click in the script (inside Unity) in order to open it in VS? 6) Does your VS has a C# compiler? (In other words, does VS lets you make C# projects)

Comment: @shubhamsharma in some pages they said that Unity 2017 doesn't support VS due a .NET compatibility issue. Microsoft recommends use Unity 2018.2, or .3, but not bellow.

Comment: @shubhamsharma 7) Have you tried to enable .NET 4.x scripting runtime and profile in Unity. [This page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2017) has instructions. That lets you use newer C# versions! In that link, there are also another suggestions. If not, you can also change the .NET version of VS instead of Unity, [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/077cf744-7e5a-4231-90c5-25b68680d218/i-cant-change-target-framework-visual-studio-2017?forum=visualstudiogeneral) are instructions.

Comment: @shubhamsharma If you use .NET 3.5 you can try [downloading .NET 3.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=22) from Microsoft. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff382215(v=vs.140)) they said you should download the .NET Framework.

Comment: @shubhamsharma, by the way, are you seing [this message](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2017-1-1-and-vs-2017-project-target-framework-not-installed.496510/). Maybe there is a solution.